# response.isSuccessful() Android Form Clear Problem

Tags: java, android

When finished progress, i want clear the page. it is upload page, when the file upload, page show seccess page but i dont clear the page text etc. how can i fix it.

```
   Call<ApiResponse> request = service.uploadPack(body,parts,stickersList.size(),id_ser,key_ser,edit_text_input_name.getText().toString().trim(),edit_text_input_publisher.getText().toString().trim(),edit_text_input_email.getText().toString().trim(),edit_text_input_website.getText().toString().trim(),edit_text_input_privacy.getText().toString().trim(),edit_text_input_license.getText().toString().trim(),getSelectedCategories());
    request.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Toasty.success(getApplication(),getResources().getString(R.string.pack_upload_success),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else{
                Toasty.error(getApplication(),getResources().getString(R.string.error_server),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            hideProgress();
        }
```

Comment: " I want clear the page". What do you mean?

Comment: it have form name and surname. it sent but it dont clear the text(name-surname).

Comment: Just set your textView text to an empty String after getting the server response

Comment: i know it, but how

Comment: Are you making this call from an activity? Have you access to those textViews?

Comment: we can reflesh page. After progress we can reflesh the page.

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about. If you have more code pls share it so I can help.

Comment: when progress finished. i want to reflesh the page.  Toasty.success aftter this it wait  short time then it  reflesh page.